# Action Creators Undefined

Tags: react-redux

I'm new to redux, and I'm trying to update my app's state by dispatching the action creator function fetching() in my container file. When I try running my app, I get a "Cannot read property 'fetching' of undefined" error. Why is that?

```
//popular reducer
const FETCHING = 'FETCHING'

export function fetching() {
  return {
    type: FETCHING,
  }
}

const initialState = {
  isFetching: false,
}

export default function popular(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCHING:
      return {
        isFetching: true,
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

//Popular Container
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as popularActionCreators from 'redux/popular'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class PopularContainer extends React.Component {

  handleFetch() {
    this.props.fetching() //Cannot read property 'fetching' of undefined
  }  
}

PopularContainer.propTypes = {
  isFetching: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  fetching: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    isFetching: state.isFetching
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(popularActionCreators, dispatch)
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(PopularContainer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error, it's not the action creator that's undefined, but `this.props`.

You didn't show where `handleFetch()` is called, but most likely you need to bind it to the class instance. 
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

```
class PopularContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleFetch = this.handleFetch.bind(this);
  }

  handleFetch() {
    this.props.fetching()
  }

  render() {
    // Your render method here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about that! I usually use class properties transform to avoid binding functions in classes.